# SQL Query Get COLUMN1 value even COLUMN 2 has value or NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these data in my database

```
Batch_Leads             CSP
BATCH 01_JUL 17_CURO    NULL
BATCH 01_JUL 17_STR     NULL
BATCH 02_JUL 17_SPI     NULL
BATCH 01_JUL 17_SPI     NULL
BATCH 03_JUL 17_CURO    NULL
BATCH 02_JUL 17_CURO    NULL
BATCH 01_JUL 17_CURO    CURO
BATCH 02_JUL 17_CURO    CURO
BATCH 03_JUL 17_CURO    CURO
BATCH 01_JUL 17_CURO    SPI
BATCH 02_JUL 17_SPI     SPI
BATCH 01_JUL 17_SPI     SPI
BATCH 01_JUL 17_STR     Sterling
```

And here is what I work so far now

```
DECLARE @DateFrom date = '7/17/2017',
@DateTo date = '7/17/2017',
@CSP nvarchar(max) = N'CURO',
@Batch nvarchar(max) = 'BATCH 02_JUL 17_CURO'

DECLARE @DTimeFrom datetime,
@DTimeTo datetime

SET @DTimeFrom = @DateFrom
SET @DTimeTo = DATEADD(s,-1,CONVERT(Datetime,DATEADD(d,1,@DateTo)))


SELECT *--'1' as [SORT],'OverAll','FACTORS' as [Label],'Touched Leads',FORMAT(COUNT(*),'##,##0') as [Touched Leads],'SCPL' as [Link]
FROM [SCPL].[dbo].[SCPL_EOD_CSP]
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
AND 
(
    @Batch = 'All Batch'
    OR
    [BATCH_LEADS] COLLATE database_default IN ( SELECT value FROM dbo.FnSplit (@Batch,',')) --OR [BATCH_LEADS] <> NULL
)
--and [CSP] = @CSP
```

It works fine If I specify `Batch_Leads` and `CSP` it will display all the `Batch_Leads` I filtered with even the `CSP` is null (because i did not use the CSP as filter. However If I specify `CURO` in CSP and `All Batch` for `Batch_Leads` it will display all datas including `Sterling` because I did not filter with `CSP` column but when I use `CSP` it will not display datas with null. Thats why I comment it. Is it possible to display all batchleads with `CURO` if I specify in CSP `CURO`? is the `LIKE` is the only way? because I dont want to use `LIKE` cause I think I might have a problem with it in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use

> @CSP

or

> BATCH_LEADS

as a filter, all you really need to do is:

```
SELECT *--'1' as [SORT],'OverAll','FACTORS' as [Label],'Touched Leads',FORMAT(COUNT(*),'##,##0') as [Touched Leads],'SCPL' as [Link]
FROM [SCPL].[dbo].[SCPL_EOD_CSP]
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
AND 
(
    @Batch = 'All Batch'
    OR
    [BATCH_LEADS] COLLATE database_default IN ( SELECT value FROM dbo.FnSplit (@Batch,',')) 
OR isnull([BATCH_LEADS],'') <> ''
)
and   isnull([CSP],'') = @CSP
```

Comment: Although your query is absolutely right .When my `@CSP = 'CURO'` and `@Batch = 'All Batch'` it still dont display datas with `Batch_Leads` that have `CURO` on them

Comment: Sorry sir, but it still dont display the desired output

Comment: Please specify the result set that you are looking for? I think I am not exactly clear from the wording of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want either one of two things:

(1) Sometimes you want to filter by `@CSP`, but sometimes you don't want to filter by it.

Then, when you want to ignore filter, do this:

```
SET @CSP = NULL
```

And in your `WHERE` clause, always keep this:

```
AND [CSP] = ISNULL(@CSP, [CSP])
```

You could also do the same for batch instead of writing text 'All Batch'.

(2) When you filter by `@CSP`, you want `NULL` to be also shown.

Then, you could just add this to your `WHERE` clause:

```
AND ISNULL([CSP], @CSP) = @CSP
```

Hopefully I'm guessing you right.